# How to integrate Geodjango with Google Maps API 3?

Tags: javascript, json, django, google-maps-api-3, geodjango

I have a geodjango queryset containing several fields but want to use only `user_name` and `location` (a point field) which I want to use as a marker in google maps API 3.

Bear with me as I don’t know Javascript and I have a series of questions. 
Take this as conceptual brainstorming for a novice:

1. My SO search suggests that I need to serialize the queryset objects
   to JSON. I use the built-in serializer module to convert to JSON.

    I think the JSON objects are converted in `views.py` (let’s
   call it `json_data`). Are these JSON objects stored in the PostGIS database? Wouldn’t that be redundant?
2. Furthermore, how do I reference them in the `map.js` (google maps
   API 3) javascript file? 
    I want to (import?link?) JSON objects to display them as location markers.
3. I want to know how to declare and iterate the javascript variable
   `locations`.

```js
For var(i=0;i< locations.length;i++){[
[json_data.user_name, json_data.point],
]

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.279504, -123.1162),
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Guide me if I went unnecessarily convoluted way to do a simple task.

Comment: I'm not familiar with _geodjango_ but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23077089/863110) question will help you? It's show how to integrate geodjango in the javascript file. Once your will succeed to render a javascript array in the file it will easy to integrate it with the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

1. No, what you are doing is not redundant and nothing get's written to the database from those answers.
2. You need to make a `getJSON()` or similar call to your API's endpoint to access the data.
3. You can do it on the 2nd step's call and declare it as a list.

What you are thinking is pretty much correct but there is room for improvement (thus the long answer below).

---

**Answer:**

Some time ago I read a [very good initiation tutorial on building a GIS application with geodjango and google maps](https://github.com/invisibleroads/invisibleroads-tutorials/blob/master/geodjango-googlemaps-build.rst#view-waypoints). Read it and it should give you a great jump start.

After you read that we will follow a somewhat different way which leaves more room to play around with your front-end (use react for example or whatever comes to mind).

*The back-end:*

1. Create a view to retrieve the information you want (`user_name`, `location`) as JSON, using the [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) queryset method which returns a list of dictionaries. 
   Since we have to JSONify a list, we will use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and we will mark it as unsafe:

   ```
   from django.http import JsonResponse

   def my_view(request):
       resp = MyModel.objects.all().values('user_name', 'location')
       return JsonResponse(list(resp), safe=False)
   ```
2. Add an endpoint to access that view on `urls.py`:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       ...
       url(r'^my_endpoint/$', my_view, name='my_endpoint'),
       ...
   ]
   ```

   Now whenever we access the `my_endpoint/` we will get a JSON representation of every object's `user_name` and `location` in our database which will look like this:

   ```
   [
     {user_name: a_user, location: [lat, lng]},
     {user_name: another_user, location: [lat, lng]},
     ...
   ]
   ```

*Moving to the front-end now:*

1. Make a `getJSON()` or an `ajax()` or any other type of call to the API and in the same time create a marker list (close to what @MoshFeu suggests):

   ```
   let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.279504, -123.1162),
       zoom: 14,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   let markers = [];

   $.getJSON( "my_base_url/my_endpoint", function(data) {
       $.each(data, function() {
           markers.push(
               new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: {
                       lat: data['location'][0], 
                       lng: data['location'][1]
                   },
                   map: map,
                   icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
               })     
           );
       });
   });
   ...
   ```

And we are pretty much done!

You don't need to make any special serialization to your data.
You can query the data from any type of front-end you can imagine which gives you designing freedom.

Comment: I appreciate your dedicated answer.

Comment: Happy to help @Kaleab

Comment: I had 'GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/my_endpoint/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)' error on the getJSON request. What does this mean and how do i solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @Kaleab maybe those 2 posts can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464834/django-method-not-allowed-post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800061/django-method-not-allowed-on-function-based-view-fbv

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I read on Django 1.11 documentation Geoqueryset is deprecated. " Using GeoQuerySet methods is now deprecated in favor of the new Geographic Database Functions." I got an error - " Geoqueryset object is not callable" in the CMD console. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kaleab  I do not believe that it is related to my answer, but without a look at your code I cannot say for sure, you can make a new post with more details on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My use-case. I used `django.contrib.gis` (`django.contrib.gis.db.models.PolygonField`) and needed to replace default map with Google maps + change default map coordinates, zoom, etc.

TL;DR

- I created a new app called `gis_addons` with custom template and widget to use.
- I instructed my model admin (using `formfield_overrides`) to use my own map widget.

Make sure to add the `gis_addons` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

**File: gis_addons/templates/gis_addons/openlayers_googlemaps.html**

```
{% extends "gis/openlayers.html" %}

{% load i18n l10n %}

{% block base_layer %}
var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [new ol.Attribution({ html: '<a href=""></a>' })],
        maxZoom: 25,
        url: "http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga"
    })
});
{% endblock %}

{% block options %}var options = {
  base_layer: base_layer,
  geom_name: '{{ geom_type }}',
  id: '{{ id }}',
  map_id: '{{ id }}_map',
  map_options: map_options,
  map_srid: {{ map_srid|unlocalize }},
  name: '{{ name }}',
  default_lat: 53.2193835,
  default_lon: 6.5665018,
  default_zoom: 15
};
{% endblock %}
```

**File: gis_addons/widgets.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import OpenLayersWidget

class GoogleMapsOpenLayersWidget(OpenLayersWidget):
    """Google Maps OpenLayer widget."""

    template_name = 'gis_addons/openlayers_googlemaps.html'
```

**File: my_app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyModel(models.Model):

    # ...

    coordinates = gis_models.PolygonField(
        verbose_name=_("Geo coordinates"),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**File: my_app/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PolygonField
from gis_addons.widgets import GoogleMapsOpenLayersWidget
from my_app.models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # ...

    formfield_overrides = {
        PolygonField: {"widget": GoogleMapsOpenLayersWidget}
    }
```